# How to catch the status code when fetch fails using async await

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

**Context**

I am going from using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for one of my [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) request (which I use inside a [Vuex action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html), but this is not necessary to understand my issue).

Using the code below, I am able to provide the end user an error message depending the status code of my response in case the request failed.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/book", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
}).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 429) {
      // displaying "wow, slow down mate"
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
      // displaying "hm, what about no?"
    } else {
      // displaying "dunno what happened \_(ツ)_/¯"   
    }

    throw new Error(response);
  } else {
    return response.json();
  }
}).then(books => {
  // storing my books in my Vuex store
})
.catch(error => {
  // storing my error onto Sentry
});
```

**Issue**

Using `async/await`, this is what my code looks like now:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/book", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  });

  const books = await response.json();

  // storing my books
} catch(exception) {
  // storing my error onto Sentry
}
```

**Question**

How can I figure out which status code my response returned in case it failed using `async/await`?

If I am using this in the wrong way, just do not hesitate to correct me with a better pattern.

**Notes**

I have made a JSFiddle to test the issue live. Feel free to update it.

https://jsfiddle.net/180ruamk/

Comment: Exactly the same when you wasn't using `async / await`..  `response.status`  etc.

Comment: But to be the same as your `thenable`, your `const books` wants to be inside your catch..

Comment: I tried but I cannot access my `response.status` right after the `await fetch()` because it goes right into the `catch(exception)` block, and the exception misses the response data.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be exactly the same code as in your `then` callback:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/book", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 429) {
      // displaying "wow, slow down mate"
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
      // displaying "hm, what about no?"
    } else {
      // displaying "dunno what happened \_(ツ)_/¯"   
    }
    throw new Error(response);
  }
  const books = await response.json();

  // storing my books
} catch(exception) {
  // storing my error onto Sentry
}
```